# Obtaining the private key from an SSL certificate managed by GCP

Tags: ssl-certificate, private-key, gcloud

I'm using Google Kubenetes Engine and I put an SSL certificate on my Ingress using [Google-managed certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#managed-certs)
I've discovered I can view the certificate using this command:

```
gcloud beta compute ssl-certificates describe certificate-name
```

However that doesn't show the private key of the certificate. Is there any way I can get the private key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. [From the documentation:](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates#viewing_ssl_certificate_resource_properties)

> Note: Your private key is stored securely at Google and cannot be
>   viewed.